# Is there any way to create an shortcut desktop to a Node.js (npm) application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file, executable

Inexperienced users want to "see" the app that I've created in Node.js, but they don't want to use the console. According to them, it's a good idea to install it, and with a simple click, in desktop, they could "see" it.

They want to run the Node.js app as a Windows program. That's all!

How can I do it? Should I create a batch file?

Comment: Yeah, making a .bat file is probably the easiest/most direct approach.  More of less mimic what you'd have them run in cli, and you can even have it open a browser window mitigate any issues with the host/port

Answer (score 10, accepted):

****SOLVED****

An .bat file, renamed as "appstart.bat"

```
cd C:\Users\MyUser\MyApp
npm start
```

With shortcut in desktop.

Comment: I would add the `/D` switch to `cd` to avoid trouble when the current working directory resides on another drive; and if `npm` is a batch file on its own, prepend `call` (it does not actually make a difference here, because `npm` is the last command line anyway, but if you put more commands here afterwards, execution only returns to this batch file with `call`; in case `npm` is an executable, forget about all of this)...

Comment: This is assuming that user install node.js for Windows and stores the app in C:\Users\MyUser. For my particular case, is it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a shortcut and set "Target" to...

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "node index.js"
```

... and set "Start In" to the directory index.js is in.

Comment: This is the best answer as it eliminates the need for yet another script (batch file).

Answer (score 2):

Because Node-Red is usually installed globally `_`

a ***`Node-Red.bat`*** file could simply be

```
cd \
Node-Red
```

then use [convertico.com](https://convertico.com/) to change the *Node-Red.png* file to *Node-Red.ico*.

Slick Willy

Answer (score 0):

The bat file should look like the below

cd folder directory 
node file.js

Example:

cd users\me\documents\mynodeproject\



node index.js

When you click the bat file shortcut it will open the node command prompt and your console app will launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create-desktop-shortcuts` node module:

1. `npm install --save create-desktop-shortcuts`
2. Run this code to create the shortcut:

```js
function createShortcut () {
  const path = require('path');
  const createDesktopShortcut = require('create-desktop-shortcuts');

  const pathToYourScript = path.join(process.cwd, 'your-script.js');
  const options = {
    name: 'My cool script',
    filePath: 'node',
    arguments: '"' + pathToYourScript + '"'
  };

  const shortcutsCreated = createDesktopShortcut({
    windows: options,
    linux: options
    // OSX shortcuts do not support arguments in shortcuts
  });

  if (shortcutsCreated) {
    console.log('Everything worked correctly!');
  } else {
    console.log('Could not create the icon or set its permissions (in Linux if "chmod" is set to true, or not set)');
  }
}
createShortcut();
```