# How to build an vue and and node app for hosting in the server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

How to host a JS app (Vue + Node) on my office server?
Do I have to build both Vue and NodeJS together or build them separately?
Please explain in detail.

Comment: Separately, there are loads of tutorials out there.

Comment: @Dan and after that what should i do ? suggest me one please

Comment: I gave you two solutions in response.

Comment: Vue's deployment guide: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html, Mozilla's Node environment guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment, Vue guide: https://vuejs.org/

Comment: @Dan these are for building the app ? which i already know , do i have keep running the "node file_name" in the ofice server ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512375/is-there-any-way-to-create-an-shortcut-desktop-to-a-node-js-npm-application

Answer (score 1):

I think building an application node.js and view.js is good for small applications.

For larger applications, I advise you to create an REST API in node (with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) for example). it will be easier to maintain because the two codes will be separated and a big advantage is that if your API remains open you can call it with another interface (mobile application for example).

Comment: ya i have created api using axios,but i do have to build the apps seperately and run the "node file_name" in the office server  ?

Comment: There are several ways to put it on a server. What I do in general is a subdomain for my API, for example "api.mysite.com" and for my ihm "mysite.com". with my ihm I make http calls to my api with 'view-resource'.